# Preselect of SelectOption does not work in Template Driven Form

Tags: angular, forms

I generate a bunch of selectboxes through an ngFor-Loop together with an inner loop for the options. When the name of the selectbox is identical to an option, this option should be preselected. My code worked unless I moved to Template Driven Forms:

```
<div *ngFor="let currentFeedKey of currentFeedKeys" class="row mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">{{ currentFeedKey }}</label>
            <select class="form-select" class="col-sm-6" ngModel name="{{currentFeedKey}}" #currentFeedKey="ngModel">
                <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                <option *ngFor="let wantedFeedKey of wantedFeedKeys; let i = index" [value]="wantedFeedKey"
                    [selected]="wantedFeedKey === currentFeedKey">{{ wantedFeedKey }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

This is the part that does not work: [selected]="wantedFeedKey === currentFeedKey"...

THX

Comment: is any reason to not use a simple variable and  `[(ngModel)]` ? For me is a bit "bizarro" use a template reference variable to manage a Template Driven Form. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel), sure you feel more confortable

Answer (score 0):

There could be problem with #currentFeedKey="ngModel". Here you are assigning ngModel to **currentFeedKey**. **currentFeedKey** is refers ngModel instead of item from currentFeedKeys.

Please do the following change and try.
change:- Here we are creating a new template variable with a new name (currentFeedKeyModel) instead of currentFeedKey.

#currentFeedKeyModel="ngModel"

```
<div *ngFor="let currentFeedKey of currentFeedKeys" class="row mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">{{ currentFeedKey }}</label>
    <select class="form-select" class="col-sm-6" ngModel name="{{currentFeedKey}}" #currentFeedKeyModel="ngModel">
        <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let wantedFeedKey of wantedFeedKeys; let i = index" [value]="wantedFeedKey"
            [selected]="wantedFeedKey === currentFeedKey">{{ wantedFeedKey }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for that help. This is how I solved it:

```
<div *ngFor="let currentFeedKey of currentFeedKeys" class="row mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">{{ currentFeedKey }}</label>
                <select class="form-select" class="col-sm-6" [ngModel]="currentFeedKey" name="{{currentFeedKey}}">
                    <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let wantedFeedKey of wantedFeedKeys" [value]="wantedFeedKey">{{ wantedFeedKey }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: if you use bannana sintax `[(ngModel)]` each time you change the select, you change the variable too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here’s my solution I hope it can help

```
<select name="role_id" [(ngModel)]="userForm.role.id" id="role">
    <option
      *ngFor="let profile of profiles"
       [value]="profile.id"
       >
     {{profile.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In my case I used ids, in your case the code might look like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let currentFeedKey of currentFeedKeys" class="row mb-3">
<label class="form-label" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">{{ currentFeedKey }}</label>
<select class="form-select" class="col-sm-6" [(ngModel)]="currentFeedKey" name="{{currentFeedKey}}" #currentFeedKey="ngModel">
    <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let wantedFeedKey of wantedFeedKeys; let i = index" 
        [value]="wantedFeedKey">
        {{ wantedFeedKey }}
    </option>
</select>
```